# matrix differentials for the product of three functions of matrixes

Tags: calculus, matrices, partial-derivative, differential

Can anyone give me an expression for following differential problem:

$$ \frac{\partial f_1(X)^Tf_2(X)f_3(X)}{\partial X} = ?$$

where $ X $ is a matrix, $ f_1(X) $ is a vector, $f_2(X)$  is a matrix, and $ f_3(X)$  is a vector, so $f_1(X)^Tf_2(X)f_3(X)$ is a scalar.

Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried the product rule?

Comment: The original formula is kind of complicate, so i have no idea how to apply product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a repeated application of the product rule.

Let $\phi(x) = \phi_1(x) \phi_2(x) \phi_3(x)$, and $\eta(x) = \phi_1(x) \phi_2(x)$. Then $\phi(x) = \eta(x) \phi_3(x)$.

Then, using the product rule, we have $D\phi(x)(h) = D\eta(x)(h) \phi_3(x)+ \eta (x) D\phi_3(x)(h)$ and $D\eta(x)(h) = D\phi_1(x)(h) \phi_2(x)+ \phi_1(x) D\phi_2(x)(h)$.

Combining gives:
$D\phi(x)(h) = ( D\phi_1(x)(h) \phi_2(x)+ \phi_1(x) D\phi_2(x)(h) ) \phi_3(x)+ \phi_1(x) \phi_2(x) D\phi_3(x)(h)$, and so
$$D\phi(x)(h) = D\phi_1(x)(h) \phi_2(x) \phi_3(x)+ \phi_1(x) D\phi_2(x)(h)  \phi_3(x)+ \phi_1(x) \phi_2(x) D\phi_3(x)(h)$$
If $\phi_1(x) = f_1(x)^T$, then since $X \mapsto x^T$ is a linear operation, we have $D\phi_1(x)(h) = (Df(x)(h))^T$.

Letting $f_i(x) = \phi_i(x)$ for $i=2,3$ and substituting gives:
$$Df(x)(h) = (Df(x)(h))^T f_2(x) f_3(x)+ f_1(x)^T Df_2(x)(h)  f_3(x)+ f_1(x)^T f_2(x) Df_3(x)(h)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm so busy recently, and just see your answer. I differentiate the equation just as what you said, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subscripts, give each of the constituent functions a distinct name $(f_1,f_2,f_3) \,\to\, (f,G,h)$ and reserve the use of subscripts for matrix/vector components.

Calculate the differential of the function
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\left(\grad{#1}{#2}\right)}
\phi &= f^TGh \\
d\phi
 &= df^TGh &\,+\: f^TdG\,h &\,+\, f^TG\,dh \\
 &= h^TG^Tdf &\,+\: f^TdG\,h &\,+\, f^TG\,dh \\
}$$
The component-wise gradients are simply
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{X_{jk}}
 &= h^TG^T\gradLR{f}{X_{jk}}
\,+\, f^T\gradLR G{X_{jk}}h
\,+\, f^TG\gradLR h{X_{jk}} \\
}$$